# button click every interval c#

Tags: c#, button, timer, click

I have a button where I want to it to click every 5 seconds.

I also have another button where the first button will stop clicking.

This is the code so far I have

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 5000 };
        timer.Start();
}
```

How do I go on about achieving this?

Comment: Creating new timer on every timer1 tick seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

if the button will set timer start/stop called 'ControlButton', and another one called 'DoJobButton'. Setup a timer interval = 5000 like your code. and in's tick event have this code only

```
DoJobButton.PerformClick();
```

this will trigger DoJobButton button's click action.
and set timer enable/disable in ControlButton's click event.
I think this is enough for your goal.